# Java 10 maven nashorn sendbox "Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2"

Tags: java, maven

Я использую Java 10 + Maven + Nashorn Sendbox.

Но при попытке собрать проект с помощью Maven возникает ошибка (В Intelij все работает)

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-maven-j10: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:test-maven-j10:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 at specified path (My secret path)/JDKs/jdk-10.0.1/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]`

Если посмотреть внутрь Nashorn-а можно увидеть такую зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Я правильно понял что Nashorn Sendbox предполагает что у меня есть файл `lib/tools.jar` в той же папке что и мой JDK? Если да, то откуда его можно взять?

Answer (score 0):

[В Java 9 удалили tools.jar.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-A78CC891-701D-4549-AA4E-B8DD90228B4B)

Попробуйте заменить объявление зависимости на

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.13</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```