# Не собирается проект

Tags: java, maven, eclipse, jdk11

Импортировал проект отсюда: https://github.com/processtech/runawfe-free-server. Собираю в эклипсе с помощью мавена. Подскажите в чем беда?

```
>[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) on project wfe->core: You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse >build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well -> [Help 1]
>[ERROR] 
>[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>[ERROR] 
>[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following >articles:
>[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>[ERROR] 
>[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
>[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :wfe-core
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java 10 maven nashorn sendbox “Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/848957/204271)

Answer (score 0):

Решил. Поставил JDK 8 и все заработало.